# What is this symbol?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I ran up to this symbol, but there was nothing there. I've only just started so I'm not sure what this means or why it was so prominent on my map, but it is.

[image]

...What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is your custom marker, you can place those on your map by hitting square over a spot on the map. Those are just used so you can see on your minimap which direction you need to go to get to your destination.

Comment: Oh, odd. I didn't place it down. I found another near where I got out of the car in a different area, too. Do you know if they get placed automatically?

Comment: Yeah I think the game does place down these markers automatically sometimes, still not 100% sure on what situations would cause it since I am pretty much at the exact same spot in the game you are in this. But I am 100% sure that marker is your custom waypoint marker.

Comment: Yeah I realized right when I saw your answer that there was a map legend that totally says what it is. I feel a bit dumb now. Also, side note, do you have this on PS4?

Comment: Yup I got the PS4 version of this today loving it to death.

Comment: What's your PSN? Mine is on my profile.

Comment: Every time you travel somewhere with Regalia, game automatically places this marker to the place, where Regalia will stop.